# How can I create a read-only SWT text that is impossible to select? (by keybord and mouse)

Tags: select, text, swt, readonly

How can I create a  read-only SWT text that is impossible to select? (by keyboard and mouse)

for example:

```
Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.READ_ONLY);
text.append("text text text text text text text text text text text text text ");
text.setSelection(10, 60); // If only I could write here something that could turn the text impossible to select, just like if it were a label.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a Label instead. Or use Text's `setEnabled` and `setEditable` methods.

Answer (score 2):

In case Enablad property using you can`t copy text from it.

Comment: Please clarify your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I advise to make tihs. You can create yor own widjet that contain two text box. We may name it OurTextBox. The First created as usaly, second as readonly (with SWT.READONLY flag). You may use StackLayout for layout. Then you should define some properties and methods. 
Main of this: 
SetText(); getText();
SetReadonly();

When SetReadonly is invoked you can show one of two internal TextBox. 
Unfortunately, this is the only solution to dynamically ReadOnly